# django & jquery mobile - testing what I'm building

Tags: django, jquery-mobile

I'm building an app with a django backend and a jquery mobile frontent. I am trying to figure out how to view what I'm building. What I mean is, to date, when I build my web apps (regular django powered websites) I do it all locally and use the django testing server (`python manage.py runserver`) to test what I'm building, viewing my results at `127.0.0.1:8000/`.

If I'm building an app for our iPhones, how can I view my web app on my phone while I'm testing? If I fire up the django test server, I can navigate to my app on my laptop and it looks like an app. However, I want to open up my phone's web browser to see the same app page.

On my laptop I navigate to: `127.0.0.1:8000/m/` and I assume that on my iPhone I would navigate to my laptop's IP address, so: `192.168.1.103:8000/m/`

I think I'm missing something here conceptually... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

By using 0.0.0.0, you will be able to serve files up to external computers and your iphone

Comment: Bam! That did it. Thanks a bunch! I was pulling my hair out.